# "YATAYO" what is hidden behind it?

Tags: riddle, word

I have the following riddle for you this morning:

> In the autumn scenery it looks nice.
>   It can be gray but not necessarily.
>   What is YATAYO?

Comment: Is "YATAYO" upper case on purpose?

Comment: I know it doesn't fit but First thing came in my mind was a " A Silver color Toyota car" !

Comment: Can we get a hint? (it has been a while)

Answer (score 2):

The items that are most likely to be in an autumn scenery that is of the gray color are

> beech tree bark, dried branches/twigs, asphalt roads, animals with grey fur/skin.

Out of which the one which is not necessarily gray is

> the beech tree bark

However the meaning of YATAYO is still unclear. It could be something poetic like

> **Y**et **a**nother **t**ree **a**dds gra**y** to **O**ctober

Comment: **Note:** The OP who posted the question is a new unregistered user and is inactive since this question (a first post) was asked. Hence the applicability of the [tag:word] tag could be questionable. I posted the answer that is most relevant to the clue provided.